# Drupal 8 Installation Symphony routing error

Tags: installation, 8

I am installing a second Drupal 8 site on an existing server configured to redirect a sub-domain to the new site. The Install was uneventful, but when I visit the site to confirm it is working I am met by:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

Inspecting the apache2 error.log i see the following:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: 
"Route" search.view_node_search" does not exist." at
/var/www/html/subdomain/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 187
```

I have double checked my rewrite module and it seems to be setup correctly for the sub-domain. I even tried re-setting it in the virtual host and the .htaccess file but no luck.

The directory for the sub-domain does differ in name to the actual site address, though I think this should not be a problem.

Can someone please explain what this means and how I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing cache at config/development/performance worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Any other ideas?